# Discontinuities in the $u$ channel

Tags: kinematics, scattering, feynman-diagrams, dispersion, analyticity

if we consider a 2-to-2 scattering, we have normally an $s$ channel a $t$ channel and $u$ channel. In CMS frame $s$ is positive and $t$ and $u$ negative, by crossing symmetry there are kinematics where t is positive, s and u are negative. since t and u are almost the same, just exchanging p3 and p4, i would expect a kinematic configuration where u could also be positive whereas s and t are negative and thus a discontinuity when u crosses the threshold, the only difference here would be that the threshold is a four particle state and not a two particle state like in the u and s channel. But I read that if we have a discontinuity in s and in t there cant be a discontinuity in u too.

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: I would have to look up the reference again, but is the logic here sound? and if yes why